# Chrome autocomplete? options

Tags: google-chrome

For a few months now we've been seeing the following dropdown for most of our HTML input boxes. Our input boxes have generic names e.g. Field1, Field2 and Field1 on one form is not the same as Field1 on another form, so the options provided are usually senseless.

[Example dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1wgq.png)

Anybody know how to turn this functionality off?

I don't know what to call it. I've tried searching for autocomplete and autofill but not sure if either of those terms are what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

well in the past `autocomplete="chrome-off"` always did the job, but for other browsers sometimes it does not work, so first try these two solutions and if they don't work try `autocomplete="chrome-off"`.

```html
  <form autocomplete="off"> 
      <input type="text" id="YourId" autocomplete="none"/> 
    </form>
```

or

```html
    <form autocomplete="false"> 
          <input type="text" id="YourId" autocomplete="none"/> 
        </form>
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is autocomplete and I managed to turn it off with:

`autocomplete="off"`

think I'd been trying "none" before.